# how to direct an elisp defun to continue despite errors?

Tags: elisp

I'm new to emacs-lisp. I wrote a function that kills the buffer of my main work document work.org and opens specific project files.

```
(defun load-current-files ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer "work.org") 
  (find-file "~/file-1.txt")
  (find-file "~/file-2.txt")
  (find-file "~/file-3.txt"))
```

The function works perfectly when work.org is open. However, if I've already killed that buffer, the function, very naturally throws an error saying `Lisp error: (error "No buffer named work.org")`.

That makes perfect sense. But how do I tell a defun to just keep chugging along even if it encounters an error? Can I wrap a command in an (ignore-errors) layer or something?

```
(ignore-errors (kill-buffer "work.org"))
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the macro `ignore-errors`, it is a wrap of the special form `condition-case`, use the latter if you want to handle that error.

---

ELisp Ref: [Writing Code to Handle Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html) or `(info "(elisp) Handling Errors")`.

Comment: `condition-case` is not only for *handling* errors. It also lets you *selectively* ***ignore*** only particular errors. `ignore-errors`, on the other hand, ignores *all* errors. See also `with-demoted-errors`.